# Proof of closeness of kernel functions under pointwise product

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick

How can I prove that pointwise product of two kernel functions is a kernel function?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

By point-wise product, I assume you mean that if $k_1(x,y), k_2(x,y)$ are both valid kernel functions, then their product

\begin{align}
k_{p}( x, y) = k_1( x, y) k_2(x,y)
\end{align}

is also a valid kernel function.

Proving this property is rather straightforward when we invoke Mercer's theorem. Since $k_1, k_2$ are valid kernels, we know (via Mercer) that they must admit an inner product representation. Let $a$ denote the feature vector of $k_1$ and $b$ denote the same for $k_2$.

\begin{align}
k_1(x,y) = a(x)^T a(y), \qquad a( z ) = [a_1(z), a_2(z), \ldots a_M(z)] \\
k_2(x,y) = b(x)^T b(y), \qquad b( z ) = [b_1(z), b_2(z), \ldots b_N(z)] 
\end{align}

So $a$ is a function that produces an $M$-dim vector, and $b$ produces an $N$-dim vector.

Next, we just write the product in terms of $a$ and $b$, and perform some regrouping.

\begin{align}
k_{p}(x,y) &= k_1(x,y) k_2(x,y)
\\&= \Big( \sum_{m=1}^M a_m(x) a_m(y) \Big) \Big(  \sum_{n=1}^N b_n(x) b_n(y) \Big)
\\&= \sum_{m=1}^M \sum_{n=1}^N [ a_m(x)  b_n(x) ] [a_m(y) b_n(y)]
\\&= \sum_{m=1}^M \sum_{n=1}^N  c_{mn}( x )  c_{mn}( y )
\\&= c(x)^T c(y)
\end{align}

where $c(z)$ is an $M \cdot N$ -dimensional vector, s.t. $c_{mn}(z) = a_m(z) b_n(z)$.

Now, because we can write $k_p(x,y)$ as an inner product using the feature map $c$, we know $k_p$ is a valid kernel (via Mercer's theorem).  That's all there is to it.

Comment: How do you know that the feature Hilbert space is finite-dimensional? Couldn't it be even non-separable?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik this is a valid conclusion, but should have a sentence of explanation. $k_p$ being representable as the inner product of two vectors obviously means that properties of the inner product transfer to the kernel $k_p$. The inner product is by definition symmetric and positive semi definite, hence so is $k_p$.

Answer (score 7):

How about the following proof:

[image]

Source: [UChicago kernel methods lecture](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dmcallester/ttic101-07/lectures/kernels/kernels.pdf), page 5

Answer (score 0):

Assume $K1$ and $K2$ are the kernel matrix of these two kernel $k_1(x,y)$ and $k_2(x,y)$, respectively, and they are PSD. We define $k(x,y) = k_1(x,y)k_2(x,y)$ and want to prove it is also a kernel. This is equivalent to prove its corresponding kernel matrix $K = K1 \circ K2$ is PSD.

1. $K_3 = K1 \otimes K2$ is a PSD (The kronecker product of two PSD is PSD).
2. $K$ is a principal submatrix of $K_3$, and therefore is PSD (The principal submatrix of PSD is PSD).